# Rspc: How to stub the MandrilApi dynamic template API

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails, mandrill

I have tried this But its not working I am using GEM `mandrill-api`

https://bitbucket.org/mailchimp/mandrill-api-ruby/wiki/Home

```
config.before(:all) do 
  Excon.defaults[:mock] = true
  Excon.stub({}, {body: '{}', status: 200}) # stubs any request to return an empty JSON string
end
```

How to Fix these failing test cases which use Mandrill templates through  mandrill-api gem????

Answer (score 0):

What error are you getting? For me, since I don't include Excon in my Gemfile, I had to add `require 'excon'` to my `spec_helper.rb` in order for the stubs to work.